# How to access the android default api using jquery mobile framework

Tags: jquery, android

I develop one android application using jquery mobile framework. now i need to share text via message, Gmail, Facebook, twitter and email. I dont know how to access the default android api in jquery. can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance...
Shanmuganathan

Answer (score 1):

Easy and short answer: you can't.

If you want to develop a mobile app with access to (larger parts of) the android API using web technologies you need to use one of the tools aimed at that, for example Phonegap och Appcelerator.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can. Is jquery mobile framework just not a framework for developing webpages.
And as a webpage you will not be able to access it.

Stand to be corrected.